# Find most recent observation - R

Tags: r

I have two sets of (sorted) POSIXct time series like this:

```
set.seed(123)
ll = sort(strptime("16/07/2015", format="%d/%m/%Y") + 10*3600 + 1:3600 + round(rnorm(3600), digits=3))
tt = sort(strptime("16/07/2015", format="%d/%m/%Y") + 10.2*3600 + 1:180*10 + round(rnorm(180), digits=3))
tplus = 0:180
```

where `ll` in reality has some 10^5 observations, `tt` 10^3 - 10^4 and `tplus` has length 10^3. From `tt` I construct a matrix of timestamps `tt1` by adding `tplus` to each observation in `tt`:

```
tt1 = t(sapply(tt, function(x) x+tplus))
```

For each of these timestamps I then want to know what was the most recent observation of `ll` (as index of `ll`). I can calculate this as:

```
tt2 = apply(tt1, c(1,2), function(x) max(which(ll <= x)))
```

but that is slow and I have to do this kind of calculation some 10^3 times so how can I speed this up? Given that `ll` is sorted and and `tt1` is sorted both along columns and rows I was hoping something might exist.

Here a look in the data:

```
> head(ll)
[1] "2015-07-16 10:00:00.440 CEST" "2015-07-16 10:00:01.769 CEST" "2015-07-16 10:00:04.071 CEST" "2015-07-16 10:00:04.559 CEST"
[5] "2015-07-16 10:00:05.128 CEST" "2015-07-16 10:00:06.734 CEST"
> head(tt1[,1:4])
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4] ...
[1,] 1437034330 1437034331 1437034332 1437034333
[2,] 1437034341 1437034342 1437034343 1437034344
[3,] 1437034350 1437034351 1437034352 1437034353
[4,] 1437034359 1437034360 1437034361 1437034362
[5,] 1437034371 1437034372 1437034373 1437034374
[6,] 1437034381 1437034382 1437034383 1437034384
```

And the expected output:

```
> head(tt2)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] ...
[1,]  729  729  731  732
[2,]  740  741  742  743
[3,]  748  749  751  752
[4,]  759  760  760  762
[5,]  770  772  773  774
[6,]  780  781  783  785
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `findInterval`:

```
array(findInterval(tt1,ll),dim(tt1))
#head(array(findInterval(tt1,ll),dim(tt1))[,1:4])     
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]  729  729  731  732
#[2,]  740  741  742  743
#[3,]  748  749  751  752
#[4,]  759  760  760  762
#[5,]  770  772  773  774
#[6,]  780  781  783  785
```