# Extracting names of vector by time bin

Tags: r

I have written this loop to extract the names of each element of a vector that occurs within a time interval (bin).  I was wondering if I am missing a faster way to do this... I want to implement a randomization aspect to vectors that are 1000s in length and as such do not want to rely on a loop.

```
mydata <- structure(c(1199.91666666667, 1200.5, 1204.63333333333, 1205.5, 
                      1206.3, 1208.73333333333, 1209.06666666667, 1209.93333333333, 
                      1210.98333333333, 1214.56666666667, 1216.06666666667, 1216.63333333333, 
                      1216.91666666667, 1219.13333333333, 1221.35, 1221.51666666667, 
                      1225.35, 1225.53333333333, 1225.96666666667, 1227.61666666667, 
                      1228.91666666667, 1230.31666666667, 1233.53333333333, 1235.8, 
                      1237.51666666667, 1239.41666666667, 1241.6, 1247.08333333333, 
                      1247.45, 1252.7, 1253.26666666667), .Names = c("B", "A", "B", 
                                                                     "E", "A", "A", "B", "G", "G", "C", "A", "D", "E", "B", "B", "E", 
                                                                     "E", "G", "F", "A", "C", "A", "F", "B", "A", "F", "F", "G", "F", 
                                                                     "G", "F"))


mydata

      B        A        B        E        A        A        B        G        G        C        A        D        E        B        B        E        E 
1199.917 1200.500 1204.633 1205.500 1206.300 1208.733 1209.067 1209.933 1210.983 1214.567 1216.067 1216.633 1216.917 1219.133 1221.350 1221.517 1225.350 
       G        F        A        C        A        F        B        A        F        F        G        F        G        F 
1225.533 1225.967 1227.617 1228.917 1230.317 1233.533 1235.800 1237.517 1239.417 1241.600 1247.083 1247.450 1252.700 1253.267
```

These represent consecutive times in seconds of events.  Say we want to make our intervals 5s long.  My approach is to make a vector of the beginning of each interval and then use a loop to find the names of elements occurring within that interval:

```
N=5
ints <- seq(mydata[1], mydata[length(mydata)], N)

out<-list()
for(i in 1:length(ints)){
  out[[i]] <- names(mydata[mydata>=ints[i] & mydata<ints[i]+N])
}

out


[[1]]
[1] "B" "A" "B"

[[2]]
[1] "E" "A" "A" "B"

[[3]]
[1] "G" "G" "C"

[[4]]
[1] "A" "D" "E" "B"

[[5]]
[1] "B" "E"

[[6]]
[1] "E" "G" "F" "A" "C"

[[7]]
[1] "A" "F"

[[8]]
[1] "B" "A" "F"

[[9]]
[1] "F"

[[10]]
[1] "G" "F"

[[11]]
[1] "G" "F"
```

This is fine for small samples - but I can see this would get slow when dealing with very large samples that are permuted 1000s of times.

Comment: I've made good experiences speeding up similar problems with `findInterval`.

Comment: or use `cut` or `hmisc::cut2`

Comment: To get a fealing about the required performance: How much is "very large samples" and how often do you have to apply the "time bin" grouping logic ("permuted 1000s of time")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is to use `findInterval` (based on an answer to [this earlier question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478022/find-most-recent-observation-r)):

```
mydata2 = c(-Inf, mydata)
ints <- seq(mydata[1], mydata[length(mydata)]+5, N)
idx = findInterval(ints-1e-10, mydata2)

out<-list()
for(i in 1:(length(ints)-1)){
  out[[i]] <- names(mydata2[(idx[i]+1):(idx[i+1])])
}
```

As you can see I have to do a little tinkering with the beginning (adding a first value that is smaller than the first breakpoint, adding an epsilon). Here's the result, it is identical to yours:

```
> out
[[1]]
[1] "B" "A" "B"

[[2]]
[1] "E" "A" "A" "B"

[[3]]
[1] "G" "G" "C"

[[4]]
[1] "A" "D" "E" "B"

[[5]]
[1] "B" "E"

[[6]]
[1] "E" "G" "F" "A" "C"

[[7]]
[1] "A" "F"

[[8]]
[1] "B" "A" "F"

[[9]]
[1] "F"

[[10]]
[1] "G" "F"

[[11]]
[1] "G" "F"
```

In terms of speed for the example there is some improvement:

```
> microbenchmark( jalapic = {out<-list(); for(i in 1:length(ints)){out[[i]] <- names(mydata[mydata>=ints[i] & mydata<ints[i]+N])}},
+   mts = {idx = findInterval(ints2-1e-10, mydata2); out<-list(); for(i in 1:(length(ints)-1)){out[[i]] <- names(mydata2[(idx[i]+1):(idx[i+1])])}}, 
+   alexis = {split(names(mydata), findInterval(mydata, ints))},
+   R_Yoda = {dt[, groups := cut2(data,ints)]; result <- dt[, paste0(names, collapse=", "), by=groups]})
Unit: microseconds
    expr      min        lq       mean    median       uq      max neval
 jalapic   67.177   76.9725   85.73347   82.8035   95.866  119.890   100
     mts   43.851   52.7150   62.72116   58.3130   73.007   96.099   100
  alexis   75.573   86.5360   95.72593   91.4340  100.531  234.649   100
  R_Yoda 2032.066 2158.4870 2303.68887 2191.3750 2281.409 8719.314   100
```

For larger vectors (I chose length 2000) this is clearer:

```
set.seed(123)
mydata = sort(runif(n = 2000, min = 0, max = 100))
names(mydata) = sample(LETTERS[1:7], size = 2000, replace = T)
mydata2 = c(-Inf, mydata)
ints2 <- seq(mydata[1], mydata[length(mydata)]+5, N)
dt <- data.table(data=mydata, names=names(mydata) )
> microbenchmark( jalapic = {out<-list(); for(i in 1:length(ints)){out[[i]] <- names(mydata[mydata>=ints[i] & mydata<ints[i]+N])}},
+                 mts = {idx = findInterval(ints2-1e-10, mydata2); out<-list(); for(i in 1:(length(ints)-1)){out[[i]] <- names(mydata2[(idx[i]+1):(idx[i+1])])}}, 
+                 alexis = {split(names(mydata), findInterval(mydata, ints))},
+                 R_Yoda = {dt[, groups := cut2(data,ints)]; result <- dt[, paste0(names, collapse=", "), by=groups]})
Unit: microseconds
    expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 jalapic  804.243  846.9275  993.9957  862.0890  883.3140  7140.218   100
     mts   77.439   88.8685  100.6148  100.0640  106.5955   188.466   100
  alexis  187.066  204.7930  220.1689  215.5225  225.3190   299.026   100
  R_Yoda 3831.348 4066.4640 4366.5382 4140.1700 4248.8635 11829.923   100
```

Comment: With `findInterval` you could, also, do `split(names(mydata), findInterval(mydata, ints))`

Comment: @alexis_laz Well done!!!
I have just benchmarked cut2 vs. findInterval (very interesting!):
`microbenchmark( findInterval = { findInterval(mydata, ints) },
                cut2 = { cut2(mydata, ints) })
Unit: microseconds
         expr     min      lq    mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 findInterval   2.307   3.434   4.963   4.8250   5.8595   26.001   100  a 
         cut2 590.122 623.445 709.359 714.8175 755.1235 1292.948   100   b`
The clear winner is: findInterval !!!

Comment: @mts my prev. comment was meant for you of course :-)

Comment: @alexis_laz your suggestion is great in terms of syntax sugar, if you care to post as an answer you have my +1 for sure

Comment: @alexis_laz I fully agree with your excellent proposal as best solution (you can't beat the performance of vectorized operations on a simple vector ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For performance reasons I am using data.table:

**Edit: This solution works, but is NOT very fast (as proved by the answer of mts)**

```
library(Hmisc)
library(data.table)

# assuming that your mydata vector from the question is loaded
N=5   # code from your question...
ints <- seq(mydata[1], mydata[length(mydata)], N)   # code from your question...

dt <- data.table(data=mydata, names=names(mydata) )
dt[, groups := cut2(data,ints)]  # attention: shall the interval ends be included in the group or not?
groups <- dt[ , .(result=list(names)), by=groups]    # the elements of a data.table can be a list itself!
# to get the result as list:
out <- groups[,result]
out
```

**Edit: You could replace cut2 by findInterval and do it all in one line, but it is still slower:**

```
out <- dt[, .(result=list(names)), by = findInterval(data,ints) ]
```

This is the result:

```
[[1]]
[1] "B" "A" "B"

[[2]]
[1] "E" "A" "A" "B"

[[3]]
[1] "G" "G" "C"

[[4]]
[1] "A" "D" "E" "B"

[[5]]
[1] "B" "E"

[[6]]
[1] "E" "G" "F" "A" "C"

[[7]]
[1] "A" "F"

[[8]]
[1] "B" "A" "F"

[[9]]
[1] "F"

[[10]]
[1] "G" "F"

[[11]]
[1] "G" "F"
```

Comment: Sorry, the result is just a string (would require transposing it instead of pasting...)

Comment: thanks - this looks promising. With regard to interval ends, bins should not overlap. Therefore any event that occurs exactly on a dividing line should go into the former bin not the latter.   Bins are therefore e.g. 4.9999999 seconds long not 5