# R, How to Vectorise this Operation

Tags: r, vectorization, lookup

In R, how can I best vectorise this operation?

I have a table of reference values, with a lower (A) and upper (B) limit.

I also have a table of values (X) to lookup up against the above table.

For each value of X, I need to determine whether it lies BETWEEN ANY of the values of A and B in the reference table.

To demonstrate the above, here is a solution using a loop:

```
#For Reproduceability,
set.seed(1); 

#Set up the Reference and Lookup Tables
nref = 5; nlook = 10
referenceTable <- data.frame(A=runif(nref,min=0.25,max=0.5),
                             B=runif(nref,min=0.50,max=0.75));
lookupTable    <- data.frame(X=runif(nlook),IsIn=0)

#Process for each row in the lookup table
#search for at least one match in the reference table where A <= X < B
for(x in 1:nrow(lookupTable)){
  v   <- lookupTable$X[x]
  tmp <- subset(referenceTable,v >= A & v < B)
  lookupTable[x,'IsIn'] = as.integer(nrow(tmp) > 0)
}
```

I am trying to remove the `for(x in .... )` component, as the table in my real life problem is many many thousands of records.

Comment: This type of question was asked many many times on SO. Please conduct a search for `data.table::foverlaps` or the Bioconductor `IRanges` package.

Comment: @DavidArenburg If the `apply()` functions aren't a good choice here (being no better than the original `for` loop), then what is a good option?

Comment: I suggest `findInterval` might be beneficial here, but don't have time to post a solution before tomorrow. For examples `?findInterval` or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478022/find-most-recent-observation-r and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34047920/extracting-names-of-vector-by-time-bin/34048151#34048151

Comment: [Nice answer in a related Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480031/roll-join-with-start-end-window/25655497#25655497). Note the `pos2 := pos` step to create a "range" of a single value.

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't find an exact dupe, so here's a possible solution using `data.table::foverlaps`. First we need to add an additional column to `lookupTable` in order to create boundaries on both sides. Then `key` the `referenceTable` (necessary for `foverlaps` to work) and then just run a simple overlap join while selecting only the first join because you want *any* join (I've used `0^` in order to convert to binary because you don't want the actual locations)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(lookupTable)[, Y := X] # Add an additional boundary column
setkey(setDT(referenceTable)) # Key the referenceTable data set
lookupTable[, IsIn := 0 ^ !foverlaps(lookupTable, 
                                     referenceTable, 
                                     by.x = c("X", "Y"),
                                     mult = "first", 
                                     nomatch = 0L, 
                                     which = TRUE)]
#             X IsIn         Y
#  1: 0.2059746    0 0.2059746
#  2: 0.1765568    0 0.1765568
#  3: 0.6870228    1 0.6870228
#  4: 0.3841037    1 0.3841037
#  5: 0.7698414    0 0.7698414
#  6: 0.4976992    1 0.4976992
#  7: 0.7176185    1 0.7176185
#  8: 0.9919061    0 0.9919061
#  9: 0.3800352    1 0.3800352
# 10: 0.7774452    0 0.7774452
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `findInterval`

```
referenceTable2 = cbind(-Inf, referenceTable)

for(x in 1:nrow(referenceTable2)){
  tmp <- findInterval(lookupTable$X, referenceTable2[x,])
  lookupTable[,'IsIn'] = lookupTable[,'IsIn'] + (tmp == 2)
}
lookupTable[,'IsIn'] = sign(lookupTable[,'IsIn'])
```

As you can see there still is a loop through your reference table so this solution works especially well if your reference table remains small. Some benchmarks:

1) Sample set:

```
> microbenchmark(nicholas = {set.seed(1); nref = 5; nlook = 10; referenceTable <- data.frame(A=runif(nref,min=0.25,max=0.5), B=runif(nref,min=0.50,max=0.75)); lookupTable <- data.frame(X=runif(nlook),IsIn=0); for(x in 1:nrow(lookupTable)){v   <- lookupTable$X[x]; tmp <- subset(referenceTable,v >= A & v < B); lookupTable[x,'IsIn'] = as.integer(nrow(tmp) > 0)}}, 
+                mts = {set.seed(1); nref = 5; nlook = 10; referenceTable <- data.frame(A=runif(nref,min=0.25,max=0.5), B=runif(nref,min=0.50,max=0.75)); lookupTable <- data.frame(X=runif(nlook),IsIn=0); referenceTable2 = cbind(-Inf, referenceTable); for(x in 1:nrow(referenceTable2)){tmp <- findInterval(lookupTable$X, referenceTable2[x,]); lookupTable[,'IsIn'] = lookupTable[,'IsIn'] + (tmp == 2);}; lookupTable[,'IsIn'] = sign(lookupTable[,'IsIn'])},
+                david = {set.seed(1); nref = 5; nlook = 10; referenceTable <- data.frame(A=runif(nref,min=0.25,max=0.5), B=runif(nref,min=0.50,max=0.75)); lookupTable <- data.frame(X=runif(nlook),IsIn=0); setDT(lookupTable)[, Y := X]; setkey(setDT(referenceTable)); lookupTable[, IsIn := 0 ^ !foverlaps(lookupTable, referenceTable, by.x = c("X", "Y"), mult = "first", nomatch = 0L, which = TRUE)]},
+                times = 100)
Unit: milliseconds
     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
 nicholas 1.948096 2.091311 2.190386 2.150790 2.254352  4.092121   100
      mts 2.520489 2.711986 2.883299 2.803421 2.885990  5.165999   100
    david 6.466129 7.013798 7.344596 7.197132 7.422916 12.274029   100
```

2) `nref = 10; nlook = 1000`

```
Unit: milliseconds
     expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
 nicholas 152.804680 160.681265 164.601443 163.304849 165.387296 243.250708   100
      mts   4.434997   4.720027   5.025555   4.819624   4.991995  11.325172   100
    david   6.505314   6.920032   7.181116   7.111529   7.331950   9.318765   100
```

3) `nref = 200; nlook = 1000`

```
Unit: milliseconds
     expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval
 nicholas 172.939666 179.672397 183.337253 181.191081 183.694077 264.59672   100
      mts  77.836588  81.071752  83.860281  81.991919  83.484246 168.22290   100
    david   6.870116   7.404256   7.736445   7.587591   7.836234  11.54349   100
```

I think David's solution comes out as a clear winner. 
This solution has an edge when there are very few reference intervals. Note that in your example many of those are overlapping and combining them beforehand might further improve results.